# JSON invalido en DataTable

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

Código para Datable

```
$('#alumno').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {

    "url": "aprendizaje/alumnos/select",
    "dataSrc": "",
    "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "matricula" },
            { "data": "nombre" },
            { "data": "apellido1" },
            { "data": "apellido2" },
            { "data": "genero" },
            { "data": "fechanacimiento" },
            { "data": "entidadnacimiento" },
            { "data": "curp" }

    ]
  },

});
```

Este es el JSON que me retorna el servidor:

```js
[{
  "id": "13",
  "apellido1": "Jimenez",
  "matricula": "17001",
  "nombre": "Ruben",
  "curp": "dddd",
  "genero": "H",
  "fechaNacimiento": "10\/22\/93",
  "entidadNacimiento": "NT",
  "apellido2": "Hernandez"
}, {
  "id": "14",
  "apellido1": "Rivas",
  "matricula": "17009",
  "nombre": "Jos\u00e9 Alejandro",
  "curp": "RIHA102293HNTLVR01",
  "genero": "H",
  "fechaNacimiento": "10-22-93",
  "entidadNacimiento": "NT",
  "apellido2": "Hernandez"
}]
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Sería bueno que añadieras una descripción más detallada del problema: ¿qué error recibes? ¿Cuándo? Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y que completes el [tour] (tras lo cual recibirás tu primera medalla).

Comment: Aparte de eso, ten en cuenta que JavaScript/JSON son _case sensitive_, es decir, diferencian entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, por eso tienes que tener cuidado con cosas como `fechaNacimiento` y `fechanacimiento` porque para DataTables no van a ser lo mismo y puede ser la causa del error.

Comment: Coincido con Alvaro eso puede estar causando el error.

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=alumno - Invalid JSON  este es el error que recibo

Comment: Ya lo corregi, tenían razón pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error




DataTables warning: table id=alumno - Invalid JSON

Comment: El problema  se presenta al cargar la pagina dónde esta mi DataTable, soy nuevo con estas tablas gracias!!, Pero cómo  les digo me sigue dando el este Error:                  DataTables warning: table id=alumno - Invalid JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Debes cerrar la llave de Ajax antes de definir las columnas
"ajax":{
      "url": "aprendizaje/alumnos/select",
      "dataSrc": ""
      },
 "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "matricula" },
            { "data": "nombre" },
            { "data": "apellido1" },
            { "data": "apellido2" },
            { "data": "genero" },
            { "data": "fechanacimiento" },
            { "data": "entidadnacimiento" },
            { "data": "curp" }

```
]
```